# Why my image don't show up on the device where i tested it?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm using an image view like a button but one of image didn't show up when I tried to create an xml fie in the drawable folder to change the image of the button when pressed

xml layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    //the button below don't appear
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@drawable/boutton_animation"
            android:id="@+id/play_button"

            android:layout_marginStart="61dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/play_bg"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/play_bg"
            android:layout_marginTop="320dp" android:layout_marginEnd="542dp" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/play_bg"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_marginBottom="33dp" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/play_bg"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

xml file of the image of the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/boutton_animation_2" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/boutton_animation_1" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

I didn't have error messages and the only thing I expected is the button to appear on the device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not seeing your image because you are using fixed sizes on your view.

**Different phones got different screen size**, in your layout you are using fixed size on your view (fixed size is `android:layout_marginStart="61dp"` for example) and the result is that what may look good on one screen (your android studio preview screen) will not look good on another screen (your actual phone).

If you want to see your image the same way on every device you can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layoutDirection="ltr"
  android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/play_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/rose" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If you want to change your image size just change those attributes values:

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent
```

Comment: Perfect it worked and it solve my other problems i had with how can i place image and button without a major changes of their position and size thanks you very much for your help